# Apache redirecting: reason unknown

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

I have a simple php script. The script is not important. It just prints out `$_SERVER`.

When I request an URL like `www.server.com/?ref=bar` everything is fine.

However if the request contains something like `www.server.com/?ref=http://www.test.com` (`?ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com`) the server redirects to *403.shtml*.

No redirect for http://x
but redirects http://x.y

As far as I can understand somehow the server doesn't like "http://x".  It always redirects to *403.shtml* when there is a valid query string in the form of a valid url.

my .htacess file is the same both on my server and local test server and local test server behaves as expected (no redirects). So I don't it is related to .htaccess.

I'm on shared host on Hostgator. Can anyone help?

**Edit:**

Here's the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

When there is an http://xx.x it redirects to 403 even if there is physical file. However if I remove the .htaccess redirect to 403 also disappears. But I need the above .htaccess file. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Your question is not accurate enough : I guess you should post your htaccess as well as having a look on how to set up rewrite conditions [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). And make sure your host enabled the rewrite module but this looks like yes from what you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess Hostgator are using the Apache module mod_security, which will block any request that looks like a hacking attempt. You'll either have to change your script so it doesn't pass a URL in the query string or contact them to see if they can tweak their setup.